Escaping {} surrounding a variable to be formatted
I need to generate a string where the variable should end up between {}. For instance, the result should be
{0.05} and {4}

I tried to get this using
"{{}} and {{}}".format(0.05, 4)

However, this leads to
{} and {}

How can I escape { and } such that it does format it using the variables.

Doubling them is how you escape them. You need the escaped braces and the unescaped ones.

And if you're using named spots in string, you need to reference those names in format - .format(a = 0.05, b = 4)

You can also achieve it using f-strings, but it looks weird actually...
f"{{{a}}} and {{{b}}}" 

"{{}} and {{}}".fornat(0.05, 4) => '{} and {}'.  "{{a}} and {{b}}".format(a=0.05, b=4) => '{a} and {b}'

The triple {{{ }}} works.

You escape by doubling. So do one more.
"{{{}}} and {{{}}}".format(0.05, 4)
f"{{{a}}} and {{{b}}}"
"{{{a}}} and {{{b}}}".format(a=a, b=b)

Note the Stack Overflow built-in highlight in f-string.
For reference see https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax .

If you want to use str.format() then...
"{{a}} and {{b}}".format(a=0.5,b=4)

or
"{{{}}} and {{{}}}".format(0.5, 4)

Or, with an f-string:
a = 0.5
b = 4

f"{{{a}}} and {{{b}}}"

